# How can I restore app data from file folder?

Tags: adb, backup, data-recovery, restore, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S6, not rooted.

I used adb backup before factory reset as well as copying all the files afterwards just in case. I am trying to restore my memos as well as data for a game and adb restore did nothing; I used android backup extractor to take a look inside the .tar and didn't see either folder. I tried copying them through file transfer but that didn't do anything. How can I make them readable by the system?

Comment: Some apps disallow backups via adb and to the cloud. In that case you won't find them in the backup file. Please post the exact PlayStore link to the use note app so we can check if it allows or disallows backup.

Comment: I can't find it in the Play Store, but looking into it with the app found at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.sisik.apktools shows it disallows it.I do still have the folder in the storage directory, though, which the same tool identified as the source folder for the aforementioned memo app